# overloaded stream extraction operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cin

im trying to input a complex number and use an overloaded operator to handle parsing the real and imaginary parts.  If I enter a number like `1 + 2i`, i want `real = 1` and `imaginary = 2`.

Right now if I enter `1 + 2i` enter, output is `1 + 0i`.  How can I do this properly (Number has private data members `real` and `imaginary` and `operator>>` is a friend function)

```
//input the form of 1 + 2i
istream & operator>>(istream &in, Number &value)
{    
    in >> std::setw(1) >> value.real;
    in.ignore(3); //skip 'space' and '+' and 'space'
    in >> std::setw(1) >> value.imaginary;
    in.ignore(); //skip 'i'

    return in;
}


//output in the for 1 + 2i
ostream &
operator<<(ostream &out, const Complex &value)
{
    out << value.real << " + " << value.imaginary << "i" <<std::endl;

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Btw, [this one](http://liveworkspace.org/code/UedRt$4) works for me

Comment: what is the error in that code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine on my compiler!  Perhaps the issue is elsewhere (e.g. in the output)?

Do note that `std::setw` has no effect when extracting numbers from the input stream.

Remember that you may also want to consider cases of the form: `A - Bi` and possibly if the user decides to insert extra or remove spaces around the operator or the `i`.  But for the simple case `A + Bi` your prototype shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: *"std::setw is a function that modifies the output and thus has no effect at all in your code."* That is not true. [Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1S74kq$1)

Comment: It's still wrong. It limits the number of chars you can extract.

Comment: Can you show a test case because I'm not seeing that behavior in any compiler?

Comment: I should've been more specific: It works that way with strings, not with integers, of course :) See the link in my first comment, compare  `stdin` data with output.

Comment: Well yes, that's why I had updated the statement to reflect that.  *"`std::setw` has no effect when extracting numbers"*  Still wrong?